# Al hacer scroll hacia abajo me aparece el error y no encuentro el por qué

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

He mirado el código y no doy con el problema. Estoy haciendo unas cards para mostrar distintas imágenes y quiero que haya scroll, pues no se el por qué me aparece el siguiente error en DEBUG CONSOLE, por eso acudo a vosotros. Gracias.

[image: DEBUG CONSOLE]

[image: CÓDIGO]

[image: CÓDIGO DEL WIDGET]

**En las ultimas líneas de DEBUG CONSOLE pone:**

The AnimationController notifying status listeners was:
AnimationController#d10b5(▶ 0.000)
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2. Another exception was thrown: The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un `ScrollController` a tu `SingleChildScrollView`, así:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: ScrollController(),
    ...
),
```